# Setting Basic Auth in Mocha and SuperTest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, basic-authentication, supertest

I'm trying to set us a test to verify the username and password of a path blocked by the basic auth of a username and password.

```
it('should receive a status code of 200 with login', function(done) {
    request(url)
        .get("/staging")
        .expect(200)
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic username:password')
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            done();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Using the auth method

[SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) is based on [SuperAgent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent) which provides the [auth](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#basic-authentication) method to facilitate [Basic Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2):

```
it('should receive a status code of 200 with login', function(done) {
    request(url)
        .get('/staging')
        .auth('the-username', 'the-password')
        .expect(200, done);
});
```

Source: http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#basic-authentication

---

PS: You can pass `done` straight to any of the `.expect()` calls

Answer (score 1):

The `username:password` part must be base64 encoded

You can use something like

```
.set("Authorization", "basic " + new Buffer("username:password").toString("base64"))
```